# sql substring performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, postgresql, string-matching

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
id | word
```

The total rows are around 200 thousand.
I want to find sub-string in the second column in the fastest way.
I have tried with index btree and hash, but these methods increase the performance only if:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE word like 'string'.
```

But I want tune this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE word like '%sub-string%'
```

Here is the problem example: http://www.labdg.com/en/anagrammi.php?&lg=EN

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? You need Full Text Search probably.

Comment: I have tried full text search, but i think  is useful only if you want find words, instead i want  find part of words (sub-string). I have tried 2 RDBMS: PostgreSql and MySql

Comment: Then you may be forced into a brute force approach.  For every word, create additional rows starting from the second, third, fourth, etc, letters.  `string` could be stored as `string`, `tring`, `ring`, `ing`, `ng`, `g`.  Then, `LIKE 'ri%'` would find `ring` very quickly.  These entries would then map back to their parent words, but as many words share the same ends *(`string` and `ring` and `bring`, etc)* this would be many to many.

Answer (score 4):

For PostgreSQL the condition `like '%sub-string%'` can be tuned by using a trigram index.

See this blog posts for details:

http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/212-PostgreSQL-9.1-Trigrams-teaching-LIKE-and-ILIKE-new-tricks.html

Using the full text search capabilities of both engines is also an option.

Comment: Without the "brute force" method mentioned by Dems above a_h_w_n_n has it right. This is a PostgreSQL-specific option but the only way I know of indexing this sort of search.